# On Win7, a route does not appear

Tags: windows-7, networking, routing

I have currently a setup where I'm connected to the internet over Wifi, and over that connection I also have a VPN running to my company. However, cabled I am connected to a device with a direct UTP connection. That device has no other connections currently.

The device is 10.0.194.11. I set up my cabled network adapter to 10.0.194.8.

```
    IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.2.1     192.168.2.18     25
         10.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link        10.2.1.195      2
       10.0.194.8  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.0.194.8    266
         10.2.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link        10.2.1.195    257
       10.2.1.195  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.2.1.195    257
       10.2.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.2.1.195    257
   10.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.2.1.195    257
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.2.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.2.18    281
      192.168.2.1  255.255.255.255      192.168.2.1     192.168.2.18     26
     192.168.2.18  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.2.18    281
    192.168.2.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.2.18    281
    192.168.160.0    255.255.240.0         On-link        10.2.1.195      2
  192.168.175.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.2.1.195    257
    192.168.188.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.188.1    276
    192.168.188.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.188.1    276
  192.168.188.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.188.1    276
    192.168.207.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.207.1    276
    192.168.207.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.207.1    276
  192.168.207.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.207.1    276
    213.251.71.39  255.255.255.255      192.168.2.1     192.168.2.18     26
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.188.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.207.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.2.18    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        10.2.1.195    257
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        10.0.194.8    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.0.194.8    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.188.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.207.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.2.18    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.2.1.195    257
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
 11    281 ::/0                     fe80::222:75ff:fe9e:e4d0
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 11     33 2002:a00:8:1234::/64     On-link
 11    281 2002:a00:8:1234:d72:1bcd:6197:83c/128
                                    On-link
 11    281 2002:a00:8:1234:9d7c:e538:7936:140a/128
                                    On-link
 12    266 fe80::/64                On-link
 20    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 21    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 11    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 18    266 fe80::/64                On-link
 11    281 fe80::d72:1bcd:6197:83c/128
                                    On-link
 21    276 fe80::a478:c114:581b:ba36/128
                                    On-link
 12    266 fe80::a838:6f32:bf46:6ef0/128
                                    On-link
 20    276 fe80::a896:44d9:d23e:772a/128
                                    On-link
 18    266 fe80::d473:a97b:8c9e:c4a0/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 12    266 ff00::/8                 On-link
 20    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
 21    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
 11    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
 18    266 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

What bothers me, is that in this configuration, I do not have a route to 10.0.194.0/24. I have tried adding it:

```
 route add 10.0.194.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.0.194.8
 OK!
```

But although it says OK, it does not appear.

I cannot ping or connect to ssh to the device at 10.0.194.11.

Comment: Some VPN clients can be configured to deny access to the local LAN (at the headend).  What are you using?

Comment: Cisco AnyConnect

Comment: Have you enabled Allow Local LAN Access in the client, or is the checkbox greyed out?